# what is the best library to use for calling c#.net webservices in g++?

Tags: c#, web-services, g++

what is the good library to use for calling c#.net  webservices with g++?

Comment: I think your question should be: "What is a good library to call web-services from g++?". The technology in which your web-service is written should be entirely transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gsoap++ is an excellent api to use